# PyMongo sort with metadata

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query

I wondering how to convert the follow mongodb query to pymongo syntax

```
db.articles.find(
   { $text: { $search: "cake" } },
   { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } ).limit(3)
```

I tried this:

```
results = \
    mongo.db.products.find({ '$text': { '$search': 'cake' } }, { 'score': { '$meta': 'textScore' } }) \
        .sort({ 'score': { '$meta': 'textScore' } }) \
        .limit(3)
```

But I got the follow error on sort:

```
raise TypeError("second item in each key pair must be 1, -1, "
TypeError: second item in each key pair must be 1, -1, '2d', 'geoHaystack', or another valid MongoDB index specifier.
```

Anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that the solution is here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/cursor.py#L658 . To add list of (key, direction) for new approach with "new" feature '$text':

```
    Beginning with MongoDB version 2.6, text search results can be
    sorted by relevance::

        cursor = db.test.find(
            {'$text': {'$search': 'some words'}},
            {'score': {'$meta': 'textScore'}})

        # Sort by 'score' field.
        cursor.sort([('score', {'$meta': 'textScore'})]) #<<<< HERE
```

Comment: On my first try, I got the same error, then I uninstall and reinstall pymongo... now works! Read the source FTW

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded `pymongo` to the latest version, and it worked.